# Name of this place

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this

Anyone knows the name of this river?

https://www.facebook.com/grupolance/videos/1092759427413531/

Comment: Why is the video badly sped up?

Answer (score 4):

If the video description is right ('show on a [pororoca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pororoca)'), it is on the Amazon River.

Comment: One of the FB comments seems to concur with this. Quoting it, "Isso é aqui na minha cidade Macapá-AP, pena que se acabou, era top.". Macapá is a city through which the Amazon River runs.